# Шейдер HLSL - неправильная нормаль

Tags: windows, directx, шейдеры

Вот есть шейдер:

```
cbuffer ConstantBufferMatrices : register(b0)
{
float4x4 World: packoffset(c0);
float4x4 View: packoffset(c4);
float4x4 Projection: packoffset(c8);
}

struct VS_INPUT
{
float3 Pos : POSITION;
float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
float3 Norm : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
float3 Norm : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_OUTPUT main(VS_INPUT input)
{
VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;

float4 Pos1 = float4(input.Pos.x, input.Pos.y, input.Pos.z, 1);

float4x4 FinalMatrix = mul(Projection, mul(View,World));
output.Pos = mul(FinalMatrix, Pos1);

float4 Normal_4 = float4(input.Norm, 0);
float4 Normal_4_b = mul(Normal_4,World);

output.Norm = normalize(float3(Normal_4_b.xyz));
return output;
}
```

Изучаю его третий час подряд. Нужно перевести нормали в мировую систему координат, чтобы при повороте чайника нормали видимо по нему скользили. Ставится мировая матрица(только поворот по оси Y), видовая матрица(один раз при старте программы, функцией `PerspectiveLookAt`), проекционную можно не рассматривать. Нормаль перевожу в `float4` с `w=0`(поскольку это направление), нормализую и в пиксельном шейдере просто вывожу как цвет( с альфой в 1.0f). Получаю результат: нормали вращаются вместе с чайником. Когда они немного плывут в самом начале и застывают, это, вероятно, ни о чём не говорит. Чайник зелено-красный, дно голубое. Всё это предназначено для освещения, привязанного к камере, но пока я делаю нормали. Почему нормали вращаются вместе с чайником? Единственное, что меняется - матрица мира, но я на неё и множу!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чайник был импортирован из 3ds max, нужно было сделать три вещи:

1. Вывернуть нормали (умножить на -1 каждую компоненту).
2. Изменить в треугольниках порядок индексов на обратный.
3. Изменить в нормалях порядок компонент (поменять местами *y* и *z*).

Вот третье я упустил. Уже проверил, всё работает.

Comment: почему ответ дает не автор поста? я не понимаю, что происходит уже. @arhad, вы под него акк зарегистрировали?

Comment: @strangeqargo, к пользователю ИльяИванов никакого отношения я не имею. Да и учётная запись была зарегистрирована значительно раньше, чем был задан вопрос (2 дня назад и 10 часов назад соответственно). Сейчас учётная запись, кстати, удалена.

Comment: @strangeqargo, моя ошибка заключается в том, что я не обратил внимание на различия написания ников и, думая, что ответ авторский, отформатировал его.

Comment: @Arhad не понял, в чём тут проблема. Вы сделали хорошую правку, отформатировали список. За это не банят )

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я в дальнейшем буду сам давать ответы. Пока стесняюсь. Это я был. У меня на телефоне нет аккаунта, иначе бы вошёл со своего. Вы же видели мусор после моих попыток вчера. Всё нормально.

Comment: ну ок, спасибо, мне просто было интересно @IliaIvanov не стесняйтесь

Comment: @Arhad, извиняюсь, если что :-)